# How does initNumToRender works on a FlatList?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-native-flatlist

So I'm using a **FlatList** component to render a last set of data. What I'm implementing is a way of loading chunks of data progressively so this way performance is stable.

There's a prop of the **FlatList** component called **initNumToRender**, which tells the component how many items of the FlatList should be rendered at first.

My question is, when this number of items is rendered, what happens? The component loads the same number of items again?

I'm working with **onEndReached** to loat the nexts sets of data, but I need to know how this prop works to do it well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initialNumToRender` is used to render on the first time of FlatList, It is usually used when you have to load the component faster.
This props will be only used on the initial render of the `FlatList`.
It won't help you when you will update your data inside 'FlatList`.